# Polyhedron with only π/4 dihedral angles

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I have a puzzle to construct a polyhedron where the measure of every [dihedral angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle) is $\frac\pi4$ radians or prove that none can exist.  The polyhedron may self-intersect however it must be finite, bounded, and dyadic as well as have planar faces.

Here's a quick glossary of terms as I use them:

- Polyhedron: A [polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) in Euclidean 3-space.
- Finite:  There are only a finite number of elements in the polyhedron.
- Bounded: There exists a sphere of finite radius which encloses every vertex of the polyhedron.
- [Dyadic](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Dyadicity): Each edge is incident on exactly two faces.
- Planar faces: For every face all vertices of that face lie on some plane.

These are all pretty standard when talking about polyhedra.

As an example, if we were to imagine a 2-dimensional version of this problem, a [regular octagram](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Octagram) ([Schläfli symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol) $\{8/3\}$) would be a solution.  A square [bowtie](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Bowtie) would be another solution ([illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVV97.png)). Both are polygons with all interior angles measuring $\frac\pi4$ radians.

Of course a polyhedron is tougher since there is more freedom to arrange things in 3 space.

Comment: When you say "the octagram", I assume you mean the unique one that can be made as a single polygon and not the alternative construction of two interlinked squares.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, the interlinked squares have angles of π/2, so not that one.  But I'll make it clear in the question.

Comment: Hint: Think about spherical polygons first: Is there a polygon (with more than 2 sides) all whose angles are $\pi/4$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I think moishe was speaking specifically about *spherical* polygons.  It's not entirely clear at least to me that there is an $\{8/3\}$ star on the sphere where all interior angles measure $\pi/4$.  However there is very easily a bowtie on the sphere where all interior angles measure $\pi/4$, just as there is a planar bowtie with the same.

Comment: One spherical polygon that has all interior angles measuring $45°$ is a properly sized $\{5/2\}$ star. Might we form the required polyhedron as a pyramid or bipyramid using this star as a base?

Comment: In my hint I was referring to embedded polyhedra, I do not know about immersed ones, I do not even know what an "interior angle" would mean in the setting of non-embedded polyhedra.

Comment: One polyhedron with the $\{5/2\}$ star as a vertex figure is the great icosahedron, but its dihedral angle is $41.81^{\circ}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_icosahedron

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic: I would vote to reopen, except for lack of clarity in definitions. 1. The link to Wikipedia in lieu of a definition is insufficient. (The quote from the link is: "Nowadays, the term polytope is a broad term that covers a wide class of objects, and various definitions appear in the mathematical literature. Many of these definitions are not equivalent to each other, resulting in different overlapping sets of objects being called polytopes.") 2. How do you define interior angles? I understand the definition in the case of embedded polyhedra, but the general case is unclear.

Comment: I believe this is exactly such a polyhedron: https://youtu.be/tH6vLXMaCwQ. Edit: Ah, this is a polyhedron which is $\pi/2$ everywhere except one angle is $\pi/4$, so not what you're looking for but likely related.

Comment: @MoisheKohan 1. What specifically is unclear to you about the definition?  The links are not intended to provide any part of the definition. That bullet point is conveying that we are talking about objects in 3 space, the other bullet points are providing the specifics of what we mean by polyhedron. i.e. nothing exotic or skew. 2. I've just removed the "interior" language entirely.  It does change the problem a bit, but not in a way that effects the result.  Defining it completely would just be a distraction.

Comment: Arguably "interior" still persists in the problem description. How do define "every element of the polyhedron" for the purposes of testing boundedness? For example, which points are inside the bowtie when some of the angles are apparently open-ended (for otherwise we would get an angle of $\pi/2$ where two sides intersect. I sort of see what you are trying to define, but details like that may affect an attempt at proving non-existence.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is a good point.  In this case since the number of elements must be finite what I really mean is that the *vertices* must be bounded rather than elements.

Comment: Specifically: What you wrote is not a definition but a list of properties. Just ask yourself: Is a polyhedron a set, or a map? If it is a subset of some space, of which space? What is a "face"? Is it a 2-dimensional planar region bounded by an embedded planar polygon, or something else? I have a personal definition a "nonembedded" polyhedron, defined as a **map** (satisfying certain properties) of some closed surface  equipped with a structure of a regular cell complex, but, likely, this is not what you mean.

Comment: Now that you removed the word "interior", I guess, you simply mean that any two planes spanned by adjacent faces make the angle $\pi/4$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think the listed properties are sufficient irrespective of implementation details.  It is not a mathematical definition, but I don't really think it's necessary or helpful to spend several paragraphs on that when it seems that there is no ambiguity.  If there is an ambiguity, feel free to point it out and I will happily modify things, but right now this honestly just comes of as a procedural complaint.